# Script for opening tabs in Guake terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts, guake

I am using this script with gnome terminal:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal --tab --title="1" --command="ssh 1" \
--tab --title="2" --command="ssh 2" \
--tab --title="3" --command="ssh 3" \
--tab --title="4" --command="ssh 4"
exit 0
```

How can I do the same things by script but on a Guake terminal?

Comment: Related on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/75895/guake-autostart-with-several-tabs-and-autorun-different-applications

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you read `guake --help`?

```
Usage: guake.py [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -t, --toggle-visibility
                        ?ndert die Sichtbarkeit des Terminal-Fensters.
  -p, --preferences     Zeigt die Einstellungen von Guake
  -a, --about           Zeigt Guake's Programminformationen
  -n NEW_TAB, --new-tab=NEW_TAB
                        Tab hinzuf?gen
  -s SELECT_TAB, --select-tab=SELECT_TAB
                        Tab ausw?hlen
  -g, --selected-tab    Return the selectd tab index.
  -e COMMAND, --execute-command=COMMAND
                        Eigenen Befehl im ausgew?hlten Tab ausf?hren
  -r RENAME_TAB, --rename-tab=RENAME_TAB
                        Gew?hlten Tab umbenennen
  -q, --quit            Sagt Guake das es verschwinden soll :o(
```

Comment: While helpful, it doesn't answer the question. Would be helpful to others if a more thorough answer was given.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, clearly should have just looked at the help but needed to know how another application could toggle visibility - `guake -t` is just the trick!

Answer (score 7):

It works like this: `guake -n guake -e 'ssh 1' guake -r 'name_of_tab'`

This will open a new tab, execute the command (ssh 1, in this case) and rename the newly created tab to "name_of_tab".

Comment: this seems to work, but I don't understand the use of multiple `quake` tokens in the command...

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
guake -n "whatever" -r "1" -e "ssh 1"
guake -n "whatever" -r "2" -e "ssh 2"
guake -n "whatever" -r "3" -e "ssh 3"
guake -n "whatever" -r "4" -e "ssh 4"
exit 0
```

(It turns out that neither `guake -n "1" -e "ssh"` nor `guake -n "1" -s "1" -e "ssh 1"` works, only renaming the tabs does the job)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
guake --rename-current-tab="tab0" --execute-command="ls" & 
sleep 1 && guake --new-tab="my/path" --rename-current-tab="tab1" --execute-command="ls" &
sleep 2 && guake --new-tab="my/path" --rename-current-tab="tab2" --execute-command="ls" &
exit 0
```

Guake starts one process and a follow up Guake calls are sending instructions to the running process.

Therefore executing the above runs all 3 lines in one go as each one goes into background immediately (ends with &). 
(1) start guake and rename default tab; 
(2) 1 sec later we send command to open new tab, rename it, run command; 
(3) +1 sec later send commands for 3 tab

The key here  is to increase sleep after each call, otherwise commands can arrive at random timing and weird stuff will happen

Answer (score 0):

I created my own script to achieve the same behaviour (with different commands) based on Panayiotis Orphanides answer; and here it is adapted to your needs:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
guake -n guake -e 'ssh 1' guake -r '1'
guake -n guake -e 'ssh 2' guake -r '2'
guake -n guake -e 'ssh 3' guake -r '3'
guake -n guake -e 'ssh 4' guake -r '4'
exit 0
```

I can't think of a better way, but I would appreciate any comments