# Maintain terminal session after reboot?

Tags: command-line, screen, guake

I recently installed and started using guake terminal. I really enjoy the way it keeps terminal sessions active after closing the window, however whenever I reboot I have to rerun some of the tabs that I usually keep alive for programs such as irssi.

I would like to know if there is a way to either remember sessions after reboot, or to reopen tabs and rerun set commands.

For example, when I reboot guake will automatically create a new tab called irc which immediately runs `screen irssi`.

Comment: `guake --help` reveals some commands that might be useful, perhaps `guake --new-tab=irc; guake --select-tab=irc; guake --execute-command="screen irssi";` (haven't tested this but hope it points you in the right direction?)

Comment: Thanks! I got it sorted. Would you mind posting that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Related request: https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/114

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Guake can (currently) maintain sessions in the way you describe. But, if you execute the following commands, you can create the same tab every time:

```
guake --new-tab=irc
guake --select-tab=irc
guake --execute-command="screen irssi"
```

Repeat for every tab you want, replacing the tab name (`irc`) and the command (`"screen irssi"`).

For more options like renaming tabs, making Guake open, and so on, see `guake --help`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could put these into your `.bashrc` or in `/etc/rc.local` so that you don't ever need to run them manually, this way they'd either be run when a terminal is opened, or when the system is booted

Comment: I'll try it, but how do I create a new terminal tab via .bashrc? Would key emulation work?

Comment: @MrAxilus to create a new tab: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49715/script-for-opening-tabs-in-guake-terminal