# How to open several Terminal Tabs in different folders (working directories)?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I want one script to open several Tabs in different folders.

While searching I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49715/script-for-opening-tabs-in-guake-terminal) entry, but an exchange like seen below did open a Terminal with three tabs in my home folder. The error message showed:

```
Failed to parse arguments: Unknown option --execute=cd /some/thing/
```

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal --tab --execute="cd /some/thing/" \
          --tab --execute="cd /home/" \
          --tab --execute="cd /home/" \
exit 0
```

A Variation with --working-directory="/some/thing/" did also not help.
Can you see a mistake?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following works for me on oneiric. You can use this in place of your version:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --tab  --working-directory="/var/www/" --tab --working-directory='/home/' --tab --working-directory='/home/'
exit 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Your specific error is caused by not using the `--execute` option properly. If you look at the excerpt from the man page below, you'll note that `--execute` *does not* have an equals sign listed as part of the syntax, as it simply executes the entire rest of the command line. An example of correct use would be:

`gnome-terminal --execute play '/home/cjohnson/Still Alive.mp3'`

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
Using `cd` is a bit of a special case, anyway. `cd` is not like most commands—it does not launch a binary/executable of its own. It is interpreted directly by `bash` (or whatever shell you are using). Therefore attempting to invoke `cd` doesn't agree with the `--execute` and `-x` flags (which seem to want to directly spawn a child process). The same issue will occur (I've checked) with other commands which are directly processed by `bash` like `home`. Even if used properly, without the equals sign, it will still result in an error: "File or directory not found." Therefore using the `--working-directory=[DIRECTORY]` option is your best bet for doing what you want to do.

**ANOTHER IMPORTANT NOTE:**
Even if this weren't the case, you would still run into trouble. The problem lies in trying to use the `--execute` option when you actually intend the meaning of the `--command` option. In the man page documentation, it states specifically

> -e, --command=STRING
>      Execute **the argument to this option** inside the terminal.
>
> -x, --execute
>      Execute the **remainder of the command line** inside the terminal.

(emphasis mine)

In other words, it's probably not going to parse it in the way you think it should.  Using `--execute` prevents you from passing any further options to `gnome-terminal`.

An excerpt from one of my own scripts where I run multiple commands in separate tabs (names changed for my privacy/security):

`gnome-terminal --tab --command="ssh cjohnson@GLaDOS" --tab --command="ssh drattman@GLaDOS"`

(Incidentally, trying to use the `--command` flag with `cd` or `home` will also result in the familiar "No such file or directory" error.)

I hope this isn't too long. I'm just trying to be thorough.